# Swift, how to split a dictionary into 60kb chunks?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm trying to split a large dictionary into smaller 60kb chunks. How do I do this?

The reason I am trying to do this is to get past the 65.5kb userinfo transfer limit, when transferring between iOS, and watchOS. I could write a file to disk which would solve the problem, but its a bit convoluted in this case as I'm sending a lot of data.

My dictionary is like so:

`data["sessionLog"]`

The key `sessionLog` contains all my values.

Sample data:

`"lat": 000000000000,
"long": 00000000000,
"name": "adfdsfs",
"location": "asdfasdfadsf",
"speed": 65`

Comment: Are your values all of one type - like Strings? Or do you have a mix of different types of data?

Comment: No, they are all mixed.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I can give you a basic approach but I can't be certain it it would work correctly or not without knowing what the data looks like :)

Comment: @Fahim cool, see the updated sample data. Its basically just GPS data, so Strings, Doubles, and Integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that one item of data (assuming you have a huge array) looks something like this:

```
"lat": 000000000000,
"long": 00000000000,
"name": "adfdsfs",
"location": "asdfasdfadsf",
"speed": 65
```

You can do something like the following for each item, provided you store `lat` and `long` in `Double` variables, `name` and `location` in `String`, and `speed` in an `Int` variable:

```
let lenName = name.lengthOfBytes(using:String.Encoding.utf8)
let lenLoc = location.lengthOfBytes(using:String.Encoding.utf8)
let total = lenName + lenLoc + MemoryLayout<Int>.size + (MemoryLayout<Double>.size * 2)
```

Then of course, you'd have to loop through the items till you hit somewhere close to the limit you were looking for. But do note that this is provided that the String values use UTF8 encoding. So the values would change if you use a different encoding.

But hopefully, this gives you something which you can work with :)

Comment: ok thanks. But kind of a silly question, how do I copy chunks of my dictionary into another?

Comment: A dictionary might prove to be a problem in splitting up since it would be one big set of keys and values. But if the `sessionLog` property contains an array, then you can get that array and then split the array up along these lines:

    let start = arr.startIndex
    let end = start.advanced(by:3)
    let sub = arr[start...end]